# Avoid Duplicate IDs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: Question edited to be exact after Marcus reply

I am trying to practice library management and my page is for order where a book can be ordered as many time but same book should not be selected in two different selects on one page. On order page, I have multiple select dropdowns for book values coming from same database:

```
<select name="user">
<option value="1">Tony</option>
<option value="2">Gary</option>
<option value="3">Martin</option>
<option value="4">Austin</option>
<option value="5">Mark</option>
</select>

<select name="book[]">
<option value="1">Math</option>
<option value="2">Geography</option>
<option value="3">Science</option>
<option value="4">Spanish</option>
<option value="5">English</option>
</select>

<select name="book[]">
<option value="1">Math</option>
<option value="2">Geography</option>
<option value="3">Science</option>
<option value="4">Spanish</option>
<option value="5">English</option>
</select>

<select name="book[]">
<option value="1">Math</option>
<option value="2">Geography</option>
<option value="3">Science</option>
<option value="4">Spanish</option>
<option value="5">English</option>
</select>
```

And adding them in database table which has ID as auto increment for record and bookID to store book id. I am doing it with:

```
$userID = $_POST['user'];
    foreach($_POST['book'] as $key=>$item_eid){
    $bookID = intval($_POST['book'][$key]);
    mysql_query ("Insert INTO user_books (bookID, userID) values ('$bookID', '$userID' )") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

I dont want to have two record of same book ID. In short, I want to avoid duplicate entries on bookID. I have tried "INSERT IGNORE INTO" but it did not work. Also, I want to show an error if duplicate entries are selected instead of just ignoring. Any thoughts on it?

Edit: Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_books
(
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    bookID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    userID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    added timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

Comment: What is your table structure like? Do you have a unique constraint set on `bookID`?

Comment: A. Show your table schema, B. Is bookID the PRIMARY key?

Comment: Here's my table structure
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_books` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

Comment: whole practice is like a library management and this page is for orders, where same book should not be selected in two different selects.

Answer (score 0):

The column needs to be UNIQUE. Right now there is no constraint on the column which is allowing it to have duplicate values. Change the column to UNIQUE:

```
ALTER TABLE user_books ADD UNIQUE (bookID);
```

This query will fail, however, if you already have duplicate values in the `bookID` column. If you don't care about the (automatic) removal of duplicate entries, use the following query instead:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE user_books ADD UNIQUE (bookID);
```

This will keep the first found entry of any duplicates, and delete the rest, ie. Imagine having 5 entries with `bookID` 100. The aforementioned query will keep the first entry with `bookID` 100, and delete the remaining 4 automatically.

Then you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` thereafter.

Comment: Since this whole practice is like a library management and this page is for orders, where same book should not be selected in two different selects on one page. So, e.g if there is record present for bookID 100, can I enter a record for bookID 100 later for a different user or for same user?

Comment: Are you asking a different question? You initially asked how to avoid inserting duplicate ID's into the `bookID` column. I've provided you with that solution. You need to be more clear on what *exactly* it is you're looking for.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I am at learning stages and also this is first time I asked question anywhere. I am again really sorry.