# Avoid Duplicate IDs in PHP while order

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to practice PHP with a library management app and my page is for order where a book can be ordered as many times but same book should not be selected in two different selects on one page. On order page, I have multiple select dropdowns for book values coming from same database:

```
<form method="POST" target="adduserbooks.php">
    <select name="user">
    <option value="1">Tony</option>
    <option value="2">Gary</option>
    <option value="3">Martin</option>
    <option value="4">Austin</option>
    <option value="5">Mark</option>
    </select>

    <select name="book[]">
    <option value="1">Math</option>
    <option value="2">Geography</option>
    <option value="3">Science</option>
    <option value="4">Spanish</option>
    <option value="5">English</option>
    </select>

    <select name="book[]">
    <option value="1">Math</option>
    <option value="2">Geography</option>
    <option value="3">Science</option>
    <option value="4">Spanish</option>
    <option value="5">English</option>
    </select>

    <select name="book[]">
    <option value="1">Math</option>
    <option value="2">Geography</option>
    <option value="3">Science</option>
    <option value="4">Spanish</option>
    <option value="5">English</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And adding them in database table on adduserbooks.php page with:

```
$userID = $_POST['user'];
    foreach($_POST['book'] as $key=>$item_eid){
    $bookID = intval($_POST['book'][$key]);
    mysql_query ("Insert INTO user_books (bookID, userID) values ('$bookID', '$userID' )") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

As another expert here suggested, can't use "INSERT IGNORE INTO" with `prodID` as `UNIQUE` because this means later orders can not be put for already entered `prodID`. So, ideally I would need to check/compare with a loop before SQL insert and exit page with some error if duplicate is found. Any thoughts on it?

My table structured is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_books
(
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    bookID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    userID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    added timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid Duplicate IDs in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518144/avoid-duplicate-ids-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If any one having this same question/problem, I was able to solve by using `array_unique()` function which will automatically just add first row of duplicate record and ignore all laters, so my code became:

```
$userID = $_POST['user'];
    foreach(array_unique($_POST['book']) as $key=>$item_eid){
    $bookID = intval($_POST['book'][$key]);
    mysql_query ("Insert INTO user_books (bookID, userID) values ('$bookID', '$userID' )") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

I hope this would help anyone because helping people should be the aim here rather than creating problems.